# After my first log in my VM the VM screen goes black, but after the session times out and I log in again everything is fine. What might be going on?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I'm several weeks into a cybersecurity bootcamp. As part of the course, we're diving into Linux via a virtual machine. The VM is being run on VirtualBox and is running the Debian distro of Linux and the LXDE desktop. This is my first experience with a VM, so this is all still fairly new to me.

Recently, we started learning about filesystems and mounting drives. The VM included several external virtual drives, but apparently one of the files wasn't set up correctly. It had worked in previous iterations of the course since they had been using VMWare, but for some reason it didn't work with VirtualBox. After realizing this, the instructor sent a new .vdmk file and explained to us how to remove the old one and add the new one. I followed those instructions and can get the drive to mount into the filesystem just fine.

Here's my issue: Ever since changing the .vdmk file, whenever I start the VM and log in I just get a black screen. The VM starts up fine and I get the normal log in screen. It isn't until after I log in that the screen is black. It stays that way for 10 minutes and then I see the log in screen again (I'm guessing this is because it's set to do this after 10 minutes of inactivity). Once I log in a second time everything is just fine. I see my desktop, can open a terminal, and do anything I want to just fine.

Any ideas why I'm met with an initial black screen on my first log in?

VirtualBox version 6.1.14

My PC is running Windows 10 version 2004, build 19041.572

The VM is running Debian 4.9.0-4-686-pae

I don't know if the prepackaged VirtualBox form instructor has any extension included.

Comment: I see some delay in an Ubuntu VM but nothing like that. At the login screen, try CTRL ALT F1 to get a terminal login and log in that way. Is this any faster?  You probably should ask your instructor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I changed a few settings on the Virtual Machine and the issue resolved.  I'm pretty sure it was some kind of issue with a drive that it wasn't finding. I honestly am not 100% sure though what the issue was, just that it has been resolved.  Thank you for the help!